# The multi-part identifier "SR_DOC_HDR.DOC_VERS_NO" could not be bound

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is the failed query.

Failed SQL:

```
Select   SO_DOC_CD,
         SO_DOC_DEPT_CD,
         SO_DOC_ID,
         SO_DOC_VERS_NO,
         SR_DOC_CD,
         SR_DOC_DEPT_CD,
         SR_DOC_ID,
         SR_DOC_VERS_NO,
         DOC_LAST_DT,
         DOC_PHASE_CD,
         DOC_PHASE_CD_SO,
         DOC_STA_CD,
         VEND_CUST_CD,
         DOC_SH_DSCR,
         RESP_STA,
         RESP_TM_WEB,
         "Created By",
         QRY_SRCH_STRING,
         SO_DOC_REF,
         SR_DOC_REF,
         SO_DOC_FUNC_CD,
         RESP_DT_ADV,
         SO_SR_QRY.RESP_STA_ORD,
         APPL_STA_CD,
         SO_SR_QRY.APPL_STA_CD_ORD,
         SO_SR_QRY.AWD_FL
From     (
             Select SO_DOC_HDR.DOC_CD As SO_DOC_CD,
                    SO_DOC_HDR.DOC_DEPT_CD As SO_DOC_DEPT_CD,
                    SO_DOC_HDR.DOC_ID As SO_DOC_ID,
                    SO_DOC_HDR.DOC_VERS_NO As SO_DOC_VERS_NO,
                    SO_DOC_HDR.SO_CLSNG_DT As SO_CLSNG_DT,
                    SO_DOC_HDR.SO_CLSNG_TM As SO_CLSNG_TM,
                    SR_DOC_HDR.DOC_CD As SR_DOC_CD,
                    SR_DOC_HDR.DOC_DEPT_CD As SR_DOC_DEPT_CD,
                    SR_DOC_HDR.DOC_ID As SR_DOC_ID,
                    SR_DOC_HDR.DOC_VERS_NO As SR_DOC_VERS_NO,
                    SR_DOC_HDR.DOC_LAST_DT As DOC_LAST_DT,
                    SR_DOC_HDR.DOC_PHASE_CD As DOC_PHASE_CD,
                    SR_DOC_HDR.APPL_STA_CD As APPL_STA_CD,
                    SO_DOC_HDR.DOC_PHASE_CD As DOC_PHASE_CD_SO,
                    SR_DOC_HDR.DOC_STA_CD As DOC_STA_CD,
                    SR_DOC_HDR.VEND_CUST_CD As VEND_CUST_CD,
                    SO_DOC_HDR.DOC_SH_DSCR As DOC_SH_DSCR,
                    SR_DOC_HDR.RESP_STA As RESP_STA,
                    SR_DOC_HDR.RESP_TM_WEB As RESP_TM_WEB,
                    SR_DOC_HDR.DOC_CREA_USID As "Created By",
                    SR_DOC_HDR.QRY_SRCH_STRING As QRY_SRCH_STRING,
                    SO_DOC_HDR.DOC_REF As SO_DOC_REF,
                    SR_DOC_HDR.DOC_REF As SR_DOC_REF,
                    SO_DOC_HDR.DOC_FUNC_CD As SO_DOC_FUNC_CD,
                    SR_DOC_HDR.RESP_DT_ADV As RESP_DT_ADV,
                    Case When RESP_STA = 7 Then 1
                         When RESP_STA = 1 Then 2
                         When RESP_STA = 2 Then 4
                         When RESP_STA = 3 Then 3
                         When RESP_STA = 4 Then 5
                         When RESP_STA = 5 Then 6
                    End As RESP_STA_ORD,
                    Case When APPL_STA_CD = 5 Then 1
                         When APPL_STA_CD = 4 Then 2
                         When APPL_STA_CD = 1 Then 3
                         When APPL_STA_CD = 3 Then 4
                         When APPL_STA_CD = 6 Then 5
                         When APPL_STA_CD = 2 Then 6
                         When APPL_STA_CD = 7 Then 7
                    End As APPL_STA_CD_ORD,
                    Case When Exists (
                                         Select 1
                                         From   SR_DOC_COMMLN
                                         Where  SR_DOC_COMMLN.SO_DOC_ID = SR_DOC_HDR.SO_DOC_ID
                                                And SR_DOC_COMMLN.SO_DOC_DEPT_CD = SR_DOC_HDR.SO_DOC_DEPT_CD
                                                And SR_DOC_COMMLN.SO_DOC_VERS_NO = SR_DOC_HDR.SO_DOC_VERS_NO
                                                And SR_DOC_COMMLN.SO_DOC_CD = SR_DOC_HDR.SO_DOC_CD
                                                And (
                                                        SR_DOC_COMMLN.AWARD_CREATED = 1
                                                        Or SR_DOC_COMMLN.AWARD_FINALIZED = 1
                                                    )
                                     ) Then 1
                         Else 0
                    End As AWD_FL
             From   av3112jm1.dbo.SR_DOC_HDR SR_DOC_HDR,
                    av3112jm1.dbo.SO_DOC_HDR SO_DOC_HDR
             Where  SO_DOC_HDR.DOC_CD = SR_DOC_HDR.SO_DOC_CD
                    And SO_DOC_HDR.DOC_DEPT_CD = SR_DOC_HDR.SO_DOC_DEPT_CD
                    And SO_DOC_HDR.DOC_ID = SR_DOC_HDR.SO_DOC_ID
                    And SO_DOC_HDR.DOC_PHASE_CD = 3
         ) SO_SR_QRY
Where    1 = 1
         And (
                 SR_DOC_HDR.DOC_VERS_NO = 1
                 And SR_DOC_HDR.DOC_DEPT_CD = '010'
                 And SR_DOC_HDR.DOC_CD = 'GFA'
                 And SR_DOC_HDR.DOC_ID = 'ESR09141700000000002'
             )
Order By Case When SO_DOC_FUNC_CD = 3 Then 4
              When SO_SR_QRY.AWD_FL = 1 Then 2
              When Convert(DateTime, SO_CLSNG_DT, (108)) + Convert(DateTime, SO_CLSNG_TM, 114) <= '2017-09-20 02:44:23' Then 3
              Else 1
         End Asc,
         SO_CLSNG_DT Desc,
         SO_CLSNG_TM Desc;
```

Comment: what's this mess?

Comment: anything related to this error wiil help though

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in your outer query, you're referencing `SR_DOC_HDR.DOC_VERS_NO = 1`, but your inner query has that column aliased as `SR_DOC_VERS_NO`.

You need to use the aliases given in the inner query.

Change your outer `WHERE` statement to:

```
Where    1 = 1
     And (
             SR_DOC_VERS_NO = 1
             And SR_DOC_DEPT_CD = '010'
             And SR_DOC_CD = 'GFA'
             And SR_DOC_ID = 'ESR09141700000000002'
         )
```

Comment: +1, Just a side question, Did you used anything to automatically formatted the query that way? what is it??

Comment: @DarwinThorburn Yeah, I used Redgate SQL Prompt to format it.  There are other free alternatives for query formatting as well, such as [Poor Man's SQL Formatter](http://poorsql.com/).

Comment: Thank you for that

Answer (score -1):

in your subquery you use twice the alias

sr_doc_hdr.doc_vers_no     AS SR_DOC_VERS_NO[image]

Comment: that is there for SR_DOC_HDR_DOC_ID and doc_dept_cd as well .. then why the error is for doc_vers_no and moreover it is created problem for sql server only not for oracle any comments

Comment: These are two different columns (note the `so_` vs `sr_`)